# NameError in python trying to create a BMI calculator

Tags: python

```
def bmi_calculator(name,height_m,weight_kg):

        bmi = weight_kg / (height_m ** 2)

print('Your bmi is: ', bmi)
  
bmi_calculator(yerson,1.8,65)
```

Comment: Name ‘bmi’ is not defined

Comment: Is `yerson` a variable or is it supposed to be the string `"yerson"`. As you have it, python will expect there to be a variable `yerson` in scope. Also, is that indenting what you really have or is the `print()` supposed to be inside the function?

Comment: Your “name” input variable is unused in your function, i suppose it is expecting a string such as name=“yerson” (notice the quotes)

Answer (score 2):

I placed the print statement in the definition and made the name arguement into a string.

```
def bmi_calculator(name,height_m,weight_kg):

    bmi = weight_kg / (height_m ** 2)
    print('Your bmi is: ', bmi)


name = input("What is your name: ")
height = float(input("What is your height: "))
weight = float(input("What is your weight: "))

bmi_calculator(name,height,weight)
```

edit: added user input

Comment: I put the print outside the function and I am getting

Comment: Name ‘yerson’ is not defined

Comment: did you put speech marks around the name yerson (like this "yerson")

Comment: yes,what i want to do is a bmi calulator ,but with user input funtion

Comment: i changed the answer to take in user input and pass it into the function